# make a table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in MS ACCESS, I ran it in MS ACCESS:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.f1=table2.f1 WHERE table1.f2=table2.f2
```

It works fine. However, I need to save the results into another table. So, I changed it to:

```
SELECT * Into a1
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.f1=table2.f1 WHERE table1.f2=table2.f2
```

It does not work. I receive this error: "Cannot Open database. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."
Does anybody know how I can save the results in a database or txt file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really want all the fields in Table1 and Table2 in your new table? If so, change your SELECT to "SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* Into a1". But you probably don't want to do that, as you'll end up with duplicate fields. You really ought to name the exact fields you want in your destination table.

Answer (score 1):

Is the database read-only?

Some things to check:

Is the DB file's read-only attribute set?
Did you use "Open Read Only" to open the DB?
Are you out of disk space?
Is there enough disk space to create the new table?

Comment: It might be the problem. Could you help me how to give it the write permission?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But mine does not seem to have these problems. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insert into command, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(office.12).aspx

Also appears that the database is in read only mode.

Comment: Is the MS Access database on a CD?

Comment: Is this a local harddrive where you have read write permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily output the results as a .txt file or a .csv file (that you can view in Excel).  To export a .txt file:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "myQuery", "C:\myQuery.txt", True
```

You can research TransferText in help to see the options for a .csv file.

This should work easily.

Answer (score 0):

try create a new table with the values mentioned at your select.

step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE table_shadi
(
column_name1 data_type,
column_name2 data_type,
column_name3 data_type,
....
)
```

***make sure you defined the same datatypes and number of fields as expected from you query***

step 2:

```
Insert into table_shadi(column_name1,column_name2,column_name3)
SELECT column_name1,column_name2,column_name3
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.f1=table2.f1 
WHERE table1.f2=table2.f2
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no need to create a table then update it. It is perfectly possible to create a table from another table and if it does not work, then there is something else going on that needs to be looked at.

Comment: 1.He didnt want to update, he wanted to insert it to a new table 2.Thanks for your comment, new here :)

Comment: 1. I did not say update, I said **create** table from another table `SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.AText INTO Newtable FROM Table1` bog-standard sql. 2. You are welcome.